# R - converting image color values to integer values

Tags: r, image-processing, colors

I am using `readJPEG` function to read a `jpeg` image which results in an R matrix with values between 0 and 1.

Is there a way to convert these to integer values between 0 and 255?

Comment: Multiply by 256 and use `ceiling()` to round up?

Comment: plus one to @Gregor, but try `ceiling()` :-)

Comment: Thanks Ben, edited

Comment: I don't know much about colorspaces, but `?rgb` suggests you might want 0 to 255 not 1 to 256. Depends on how you're using it, I suppose.